# Increase number of decimal places in column without droping dependecies

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with approx. 1,5 mio records and I want to change datatype for one column from `decimal(18, 2)` to `decimal(18, 4)` (add two decimal places).
If I tried with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn1 decimal(18, 4) NO NULL
GO
```

However SQL Server doesn't allow this, since there are 20+ views, indexes and procedures dependant on this table:

> ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN MyColumn1 failed because one or more objects
>   access this column.

Is there a way for me to add decimal places without droping the dependecies first? Since this database is live, we cannot afford being without some structure for some time.

Comment: I don't know any way other than dropping the indices and then adding them back later.  But, you can probably handle this fairly quickly, and the index/view problem might add less of a delay than you think.

Comment: Do you try table design mode from SSMS or try to change type decimal(20,4) because of the decimal places length always the part whole number length

Comment: @AdnanAhmedAnsari Yes, I've tried that before. No success.